# How to get the parent of a Sitecore item in the item:deleted event?

Tags: c#, sitecore

When handling the `item:deleted` event in Sitecore, the `Item` that is passed in has a parent of null:

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Events;

public void OnItemDeleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    Item itemParent = item.Parent;
    if (itemParent != null)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

It never hits the `// Do stuff` because `itemParent` is always null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter passed into this method is the Parent's ID. Update the method as follows:

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Events;

public void OnItemDeleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    ID parentId = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 1) as ID;
    Item itemParent = item.Database.GetItem(parentId);
    if (itemParent != null)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!!